# Where can I find this short-story extended from the traditional recursive "Antonio, tell us a story!"?

Tags: identification-request

There is an interesting oral tradition that goes something like:

> It was a dark and story night, and the brigands were waiting in the
>   dell. And the men said "Antonio, tell us a story!". And Antonio said,
>   "
>
> It was a dark and story night, and the brigands were waiting in the
>   dell. And the men said "Antonio, tell us a story!". And Antonio
>   said...

Which goes on and on forever. Though I believe the origin is still a mystery, it is well documented in many forms. (see https://bohemiancoast.livejournal.com/164722.html for one discussion on the topic)

When I was casually researching this a couple of years ago, I came across a short-story written based on the *Antonio* variant, which extended it to a full story with around 16 layers of story telling -- each slightly different -- each telling a different possible outcome of the brigands' ransack (or not) of a passing caravan. In the topmost story, Antonio saves his lover by telling his long enough that the caravan passes.

I keep trying to find it, but have had no luck. I believe it was titled just "The Brigands", and it was hosted on the author's personal webpage. I think it was a professor at a university (so at a .edu site). It was simple static html, so it should be in the Wayback machine if it's no longer hosted.

Comment: "*It was a dark and **story** night*" - Freudian slip? :-)